# How do you swap two integer value without using temp variable?

Tags: c#

```
// Swapping value between two integer without using temp variable.
        int a = 5;
        int b = 7;

        Console.WriteLine("Before Swap.");
        Console.WriteLine("value of A is: {0}", a);
        Console.WriteLine("value of B is: {0}", b);

        Console.ReadLine();
```

O/P:
Before Swap.
value of A is: 5
value of A is: 7

After Swap.
value of A is: 7
value of A is: 5

So how can you swap two integer value without using temp variable?

Comment: You are posting a brain teaser, but this is not really the right place for it. I even think I saw the solution before the edit... Perhaps you should post to puzzling.stackexchange.com ?

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
 a = a + b;
 b = a - b;
 a = a - b;
```

Answer (score 2):

first method

```
a = a + b;
b = a - b;
a = a - b;
```

second method

```
a ^= b;
b ^= a;
a ^= b;
```

Comment: The reason to NEVER EVER DO #2: when `a == b` you lose the value altogether, `x^x==0`

Answer (score 0):

```
a = a + b;
b = a - b;
a = a - b;
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the XOR operator:

```
a = a ^ b;
b = a ^ b;
a = a ^ b;
```

This works because applying two times the XOR with the same value cancel the operation:

```
a ^ b ^ b => a
```