# Swap two integers without using a third variable for all range of integer values

Tags: c#

How to swap 2 integers without using a third variable such that it works for all ranges of integers.
I know that generally we do the following logic.

```
        int a, b;

        a = 10;
        b = 30;
        a = a + b;
        b = a - b;
        a = a - b;
```

But this logic will fail if (a + b) gives the value more than the integer range.
Is there any other logic?

Comment: you might want to refer to this post:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26274628/how-do-you-swap-two-integer-value-without-using-temp-variable

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you're looking for the [XOR swap](http://www.blackwasp.co.uk/XORSwap.aspx):

```
if (a != b) {
    a ^= b;
    b ^= a;
    a ^= b;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use xor ...

```
x ^= y;
y ^= x;
x ^= y;
```

[Source](http://betterexplained.com/articles/swap-two-variables-using-xor/) with a handy live demo.

Answer (score 1):

```
int a=10;
int b=20;

a=a^b;
b=a^b;
a=a^b;
Console.WriteLine(a);
Console.WriteLine(b);
```